# Why we need diamond operator in Java 7?

Tags: java, java-7

I'm curious why we need the diamond operator in Java7? We can simulate this behaviour with a simple static generic method, which could be added to the collections API:

Code of the method for HashMap:

```
public static <R, S> HashMap<R, S> getInstance() {
    return new HashMap<R, S>();
}
```

And we can use it this way:

```
Map<String, List<String>> m = HashMap.getInstance();
```

And code when you can try this behaviour:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Diamond {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Map<String, List<String>> m = getInstance();
        m.put("Hello", Arrays.asList("Peter", "Robert"));
        System.out.println(m.toString());
    }
    public static <R, S> HashMap<R, S> getInstance() {
        return new HashMap<R, S>();
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need it, it just makes your life simpler (i.e. you don't need to create you static method any more)...

Comment: There is nothing new in Java 7 that we **need**, only things that may make some code simpler.

Comment: I think that: "HashMap.getInstance();" would be simpler than "new HashMap<>();" And could be there from Java 5.

Comment: The main difference is that the diamond operator works with any generic type - to simulate that behaviour you would need to provide factories for every generic type too. Quite cumbersome, right?

Comment: There is a nice article about this on [DZone](https://dzone.com/articles/java-7-do-we-really-need).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you are correct that one can use a generic factory method to avoid repeating type parameters when creating generic objects, that approach has a couple of disadvantages:

- You need to write a factory method for every constructor of every generic class, duplicating its argument lists and parameter documentation.
- With a constructor, it is clear a new object is being created. With methods, this knowledge must be communicated informally.
- Callers need to know where to find the factory method. In particular, if it is not part of the generic class being instantiated, different people are likely to put them in different utility classes, further increasing code duplication ...

Comment: By the way, calling default constructor with reflection is much simpler than calling a static method, when dealing with lots of types.